# Tap is recognized multiple times

Tags: flutter

I have a Flatbutton which, when pressed should display an Image with an external link. (when the image is pressed, the external link should be opened).

Anyhow, when I press the button, the link of the Image is immediately opened and the application remains in an error state.

```
  Widget buildWithImage(BuildContext context) {
return FlatButton(
    onPressed: () async {
      Map<String, String> parameter = {
        "id": news.id.toString(),
        "type": "image",
      };

      String uri = Request().getNewsDocumentUri(parameter);
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {

        if (news.externalLink != null && news.externalLink.isNotEmpty) {
          return Container(child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: _launchURL(news.externalLink), // TODO Bug, Tap of previous Button is immediately recognized
            child: Image.network(uri),
          ));
        }

        return Image.network(uri);
      }));
    },
    child: Text(news.text));
```

}

How can I avoid this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
onTap: _launchURL(news.externalLink),
```

should be

```
onTap: () => _launchURL(news.externalLink),
```

so that it waits for an input THEN launches url